# In Android, is there anything like PRODUCT_PACKAGE_OVERLAYS for java source code?

Tags: java, android, build

PRODUCT_PACKAGE_OVERLAYS is good. But it's used for some kind of resource. We maintain many Android projects. In reality, not only resources but also java code varies from device to device. Java is not C, it doesn't support MACRO. So it's hard to keep all modifications in just one code copy. I need something like PRODUCT_PACKAGE_OVERLAYS which can override the java code in the main tree by a file with the same name from somewhere else. Is that possible? Or can you guys share the ideas about how you manage multi android projects source code?